# jquery replace '/' - regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace `'</'` in my code to `\n </`.
I tried with `.replace(/\<//g, '\n</')` but it shows error.

Comment: Certain characters need to be escaped with a ```\``` in regex. try `.replace(/\<\//g, '\n<\/')`

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `/<\//g`. Escape the `/` in `</` as `<\/`

```js
var test = 'someTe</xt</here';
var res = test.replace(/<\//g,'\n </');
console.log(res);
```